# How use Local Storage in Functional Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks

**How can I use LocalStorage in a functional component like this**

> I know how do this in a class component but can I solve this problem in this case?

**ERROR: TypeError: repositories is not a function**

```
export default function Main() {
  const [newRepo, setNewRepo] = useState('');
  const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState([]);
  const [clearInput] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    repositories(localStorage.getItem('repositories'));

    if (repositories) {
        setRepositories(JSON.parse(repositories));
    }
  }, [repositories]);

  useEffect((_, prevState) => {
    if (prevState.repositories !== repositories) {
        localStorage.setItem('repositories', JSON.stringify(repositories));
    }
  });
```

Comment: it looks like you are using local storage fine... is the problem that you want to get this part to work `_, prevState` where need to know the previous state in the effect?

Comment: when i go back to the repository page i want the repositories to keep showing up

Comment: You can access the repository at: https://github.com/paulorod07/ListGitHubRepositories  I have this error: ×
TypeError: repositories is not a function

Comment: `repositories` is a `const` that stores a current state, which initially is an array. The following line makes no sense: `repositories(localStorage.getItem('repositories'));`

Answer (score 1):

In your `first useEffect`, the `repositories` is your state which an array. Not a function.

Also, in your `second useEffect` you need to make correction to the way you access the prevState in hooks.

**Fix for 1st useEffect**

```js
export default function Main() {
  const [newRepo, setNewRepo] = useState('');
  const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState([]);
  const [clearInput] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localRepoItems = localStorage.getItem('repositories');

    if (localRepoItems) {
        setRepositories(JSON.parse(localRepoItems));
    }

  }, []); // do not give the dependency as repositories as it will go to infinite loop

  });
```

To obtain previous state in hooks, you can write a little custom hook:
**Like this:**

```js
export const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

**Usage in your component:**

```js
const prevRepositories = usePrevious(repositories);
useEffect(() => {
    if (prevRepositories.length !== repositories.length) {
        localStorage.setItem('repositories', JSON.stringify(repositories));
    }
  }, [repositories]);
```